# password_hash on existing users

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I get a PHP Error and returning empty body on hurl.it. Im trying to hash the password of existing users in my DB.

using user_id as POST and update it to my DB in a new created column

```
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($dbPath,$dbUserName,$dbPassword,$dbSchema);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  $error = "DB connection error";
}

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];  


//exisitng password
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM user_table 
                            WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");

if(!$sql) $error = "SELECT user_table error";

$i=0;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    $hash[$i] = $result;

    if($hash[$i]) {
        $check_hash = password_hash($hash[$i], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //store into DB
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user_table (password_secure) VALUES   ('$check_hash')"); 
    }
    $i++;
}



if(!$result2) $error = "INSERT user_table error";
// Set returns
if (!$error) $status = "successful";
```

Comment: Are you currently storing your user passwords in plaintext?

Comment: The "PHP error" could be helpful

Comment: ignore the PHP error. its returning empty body in hurl.it

Comment: yup previously in plain text but trying to has the password for existing users

Comment: Ignoring the error, you are certainly doing it wrong. You should be ***updating*** the user's record and not ***INSERT*** ing a new one.

Comment: Well, there is no echo in your code. How should it be anything else than empty?

Comment: This code needs a complete refactoring, that means throw it away and start again. This time work out what you want to do - Then read look at the `php.net` documentation - Then start the coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code, but the main culprit is the fact that you use `INSERT` when you should really be using `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE user_table SET password_secure=? WHERE user_id=?
```

Comment: it's returning empty body (internal server error) in the hurl

Answer (score 0):

$result will be an array, because you're using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` so you're trying to hash an array

```
$password = $result['password'];

if($password){
    $check_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```